# Parsing a user defined protocol from C and Python

Tags: python, c, serialization, protocol-buffers

I need to define a binary protocol and use it from both C and Python written application.
My question is, what is the right tool for the job so I won't need to implement the protocol parsing and building code in C and Python? I heard about Google's Protocol Buffers but their C implementation is not mature enough for the protocol. Is their a better substitute?

Comment: Are you planning on serialization of data and saving/loading from those applications, or on a RPC-like use? As I'm not sure of your question, this might/might not help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrift_%28protocol%29

Comment: Protocol Buffers C++ implementation is very stable. My approach to a similar problem is to use C++ for the protocol and C for the functional part.

Answer (score 1):

Look for state machine compilers like [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/). They will generate compilable code based on a state machine specification.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/).